# How do I create a rule in Outlook for handling emails which are not sent using the senders domain

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I subscribe to a few newsletters which are obviously using a third party service like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor to send their mails and I cannot find a way to create a rule that moves the newsletters into the appropriate folder that I have created.

All the newsletters follow a format that is structured like this:

```
Jared Spool <jared.m.spool=uie.com@mail214.atl101.mcdlv.net>; on behalf of; Jared Spool <jared.m.spool@uie.com>
```

The prolem with using the senders address for newsletters like this is that the full address that these mails are sent from seems to change quite regularly and the rule no longer works. If I try using "use specific words in the senders address" and then fill in the name, or the 'on-behalf of' email address, the rule does not work.

In most cases the subject lines don't follow a consistent format either, so I can't create a rule based on the subject line.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Such newsletter would follow a standard subject line in most cases - don't they?

Comment: No. They don't. Which makes this even trickier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement Styxor's answer:

> You indeed cannot do this with a regular “From” rule but you can
>   achieve it when you use the rule condition: **“with specific words in
>   the message header**” condition and then have it look for the address in
>   the message header.

Simple Steps (worked for me): https://www.msoutlook.info/question/709

Answer (score 2):

By comparing the headers from mails send behalf of, I found some similarities, which I could use to sort out the send behalf of mails.

Example (part of header from 2 different send on behalf of emails):

*Sender:Content-Type:MIME-Version; i=norely=3Dloebeshop.dk@mail251.suw16.rsgsv.net;

Sender:Content-Type:MIME-Version; i=inco=3Dinco.dk@mail225.wdc02.mcdlv.net;*

By setting up a rule that looked in the headers for specific words, I was able to sort out the send behalf of mails. With the examples given above, my rule would have the following in the search list:

*i=inco=3Dinco.dk 

i=norely=3Dloebeshop.dk*